# Java not found while installing Websphere Application Server

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-installation-manager

I am trying to install the Websphere Application Server (32bit) in Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64bit) using the IBM installation manager a silent install and a response file.

The commands I am using are:

```
sudo ./IBMIM --launcher.ini silent-install.ini -input 
ibm_im_response_file.xml -acceptLicense
```

In the logs I see the following:

> WARNING: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/iscdeploy.sh: 44:
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin/iscdeploy.sh:
>   /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/bin/java: not found

although this file exists, but it's a link to /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/java

**EDIT: same happens when using the GUI**

**EDIT2: I tried doing the same under Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked. Apparently there is some problem regarding the 32bit version that is related to the ia32-libs package that is no longer available in 14.04.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to Install Websphere Application Server through Installation Manager then you need to select IBM SDK provided with Websphere Application Server.

If you don't choose the IBM SDK you will be need to enter the JAVA Path in next steps.